# Attach a Wordpress.org blog to my BigCommerce Store as a sub-domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, ecommerce, godaddy

I am stuck in a peculiar situation. I have a store on BigCommerce configured with a domain from GoDaddy (**mystore.com**). I recently created a custom wordpress blog and hosted it on 1and1 hosting (**s418783372.onlinehome.us**), since bigcommerce can't host Wordpress.

Now, I want to use it from a sub-domain of my main-bigcommerece store (**models.mystore.com**), but it doesn't seem to be working since BigCommerce is the Domain Manager, but GoDaddy is the Domain-Registrar and 1and1 is the host so it doesn't control the domain.

I have tried setting up a CNAME record on BigCommerece and when it didn't work asked BigCommerece about it, but they said they can't do anything about it since they aren't the domain registrar and gave me a message saying:

> The responsiblity to show the name in the browser on the site is up to
>   the server or site admin. The Cname can only get the browser there

**UPDATE:**

I succeeded in setting up a CNAME on BigCommerce poinitng to the site at 1and1, but for some-reason, all it gives me is a `404-Not-Found` error. I was thinking this is due to a restriction on 1and1, any idea on how to overcome that?

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried adding a domain on the 1and1 control panel (http://faq.1and1.co.uk/domains/domain_xfers/dns_transfer/4.html), pointing to models.mystore.com, but it isn't letting me add a Sub-Domain, there...

**UPDATE:**

I added mystore.com as an external domain and them added models.mystore.com as a sub-domain on the 1and1 hosting Domains panel. And it works :) Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

If you pointed the nameservers to BigCommerce then you need to create a subdomain in there (Tools- DNS records).

If the blog you have is on dedicated IP then you are in luck: simply create the subdomain in BC, create an A record to point to the dedicated ip.

If this doesn't work try with CNAME in Bc
models.mystore.com CNAME s418783372.onlinehome.us
Then you will need to ask 1and1 to help with domain mapping ( http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Hosting/Domain-Mapping/what-is-domain-mapping-why-would-i-use-it-2580/ ) to map the subdomain to the blog.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel, I succeeded in setting up a CNAME on BigCommerce poinitng to the site at 1and1, but for some-reason, all it gives me is a `404-Not-Found` error. I was thinking this is due to a restriction on 1and1, any idea how to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting on GoDaddy may have been easier since you registered there. For support at least to be easier. Have you created a CNAME in GoDaddy where you registered your domain name. Pointing the CNAME to your blog URL at `models.mystore.com`?

BigCommerce shouldn't have anything to do with CNAMEs for subdomains. If anything the CNAME they're using is to mask their hosted cart URL to your own domain name.